# Installing an entry door with sidelights

Tags: doors, windows

Anyone have any experience creating a custom size door sidelight?

I would like to install an entry door with one sidelight where I currently have a window. I would like to stay in the same size as the current width of the window opening.

Have you built one? Any pitfalls? Did you custom order cut glass?

Thx!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info; exactly  what  are you planning to do? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to participate here.

Comment: This could be good or bad send pis of area. May be better off buying new, if glass is not insulated,and heat loss will pay for itself over time.